# Launching Xcode 4.0.2 application on iPhone/iPad from VMWare

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, vmware

I would like to test an application on my iPhone and iPad.
The iPhone is running 5.1 and the iPad is running 5.1.1

I am getting this error:

> **Xcode cannot run using the selected device.** No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS
> device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or
> choose an iOS simulator as the destination.

I have a developer's license and have followed the provisioning wizard in the Apple website members section. I've installed everything like it said (certificate, provisioning profile in keychain, etc..) but am still getting this error.

I've tried compiling it on 4.3, 4.2, 4.1, and basically all of the options that are available in the build section.

In the Xcode Organizer, my devices show up with an Orange icon next to them. This is the 'error' message on this screen:

> The version of iOS on “Personal iPad” does not match any of the
> versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of
> the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed
> below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is
> available here.

This is all on VMWare on OS X 10.6.7.

I've read the other posts where people had a similar problem and tried the solutions proposed (which were mostly comprised of trying to run on older builds) and nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 2):

Notice how you are compiling with an SDK version less than the version on your devices?  That's a problem.  For iOS 5 you need at least Xcode 4.2 (which comes with the 5.1 SDK).